# Volume ratio of general $\ell_p$ balls and surfaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, asymptotics

This question is a generalization of the question [Volume ratio of $\ell_1$ balls and $\ell_1$ surfaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281611/volume-ratio-of-ell-1-balls-and-ell-1-surfaces)

For any $p\in[1,\infty]$ define $\|x\|_p := (|x_1|^p+\cdots+|x_d|^p)^{1/p}$ for $p\in[1,\infty)$ and $\|x\|_\infty := \max_{1\leq i\leq d}|x_i|$ for $p=\infty$. Denote $B_p^d := \{x\in\mathbb R^d: \|x\|_p\leq 1\}$ as the unit $\ell_p$-ball in $d$ dimension, and let $\partial B_p^d := \{x\in\mathbb R^d: \|x\|_p = 1\}$. The quantity of interest is the following "ratio"
$$
\mathfrak d_{p,d} := \frac{\mathrm{vol}_{d-1}(\partial B_p^d)}{\mathrm{vol}_{d}(B_p^d)}.
$$

My question is the following:

> For any fixed $p\in[1,\infty]$, how does $\mathfrak d_{p,d}$ asymptotically scale with dimension $d$, as $d\to\infty$?

For some special cases, both $\mathrm{vol}_d(B_p^d)$ and $\mathrm{vol}_{d-1}(\partial B_p^d)$ have closed form solutions and the ratio $\mathfrak d_{p,d}$ can be calculated explicitly. Below are three examples:

1. $p=2$: in this case $\mathrm{vol}_d(B_2^d) = \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2+1)}$, $\mathrm{vol}_{d-1}(\partial B_2^d) = \frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}$ and therefore $\mathfrak d_{2,d} = d$;
2. $p=1$: in this case $\mathrm{vol}_d(B_1^d) = \frac{2^d}{d!}$ and $\mathrm{vol}_{d-1}(\partial B_1^d) = \frac{2^d \sqrt{d}}{(d-1)!}$, and therefore $\mathfrak d_{1,d} = d\sqrt{d}$
3. $p=\infty$: in this case $\mathrm{vol}_d(B_\infty^d) = 2^d$ and $\mathrm{vol}_{d-1}(\partial B_\infty^d) = 2^d n$. Therefore $\mathfrak d_{\infty,d} = d$.

From the above examples, my (very wild) guess is that $\mathfrak d_{p,d} \asymp d^{1+1/p-1/2}$ for $1\leq p\leq 2$ and $\mathfrak d_{p,d} \asymp d$ for $p\geq 2$. But of course I could be very wrong. The challenge for general $p$ is the apparent difficulty in evaluating the volume of $L_p$ sphere areas (e.g., [Surface area of an $\ell_p$ unit ball?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234314/surface-area-of-an-ell-p-unit-ball)), but I'm hoping that the (asymptotic) ratio $\mathfrak d_{p,d}$ for general $p$ is potentially easier to evaluate.

**Edit:** I realized that, because the volume of a unit $\ell_p$ *ball* does have closed forms for general $p\in[1,\infty]$, the question can be answered if we know the **asymptotic dependency of dimension $d$ of the (unit) $\ell_p$-surface area**. This question was explicitly mentioned in the comment under the accepted answer of the following question
[Surface area of superellipsoid (dice)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80243/surface-area-of-superellipsoid-dice?rq=1)
Unfortunately, the OP in that question did not pursue this direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have managed to obtain a complete solution to this problem, by applying the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) and the classical results of [Naor and Romik](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPB_2003__39_2_241_0.pdf) on the affinity between cone and surface measures in $\ell_p$ balls.

The results are different than what I have conjectured in the problem statement. In particular, it is proved that **$\mathfrak d_{p,d} \asymp d^{1/2+1/p}$ for all fixed $p<\infty$ and $d\to\infty$.** Therefore, there is a phase transition between $p\to\infty$ and $p=\infty$. Such phase transition is because of the asymptotic regime we're considering ($p$ fixed, and $d$ goes to infinity afterwards). In cases where both $p$ and $d$ go to infinity simultaneously, the question remains unsolved.

The proof idea is to first use the **divergence theorem** to obtain
$$
d\times \mathrm{vol}_d(\mathbb B_p^d) = \mathrm{vol}_{d-1}(\partial\mathbb B_p^d)\times \int_{\partial\mathbb B_p^d}\frac{\mathrm{d}\sigma_p^{d-1}(v)}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^d|v_i|^{2p-1}}}.
$$
Here $\sigma_p^{d-1}(v)$ is the **surface measure** on $\partial\mathbb B_p^{d-1}$, meaning that $\sigma_p^{d-1}(A)=\mathrm{vol}_{d-1}(A)/\mathrm{vol}_{d-1}(\partial\mathbb B_p^d)$ for all measurable $A\subseteq\mathbb B_p^{d-1}$.
The work of [Naor and Romik](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPB_2003__39_2_241_0.pdf) showed that this surface measure is very close (in TV distance) to a **cone measure** $\gamma_p^{d-1}$, which is equivalently the distribution of $X=Z/\|Z\|_p$ where $Z=(Z_1,\cdots,Z_d)$ consists of i.i.d. random variables distributed according to a generalized Normal distribution $p(\cdot)\propto \exp\{-|\cdot|^p\}$. It is then possible to use Chebyshev's inequality to get an adequate estimate of the integral term above, which yields an asymptotic formula for $\mathfrak d_{p,d}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\dd}{\operatorname{d}\!}$

This is not a complete answer, but it may lead to one. Since the volume of the unit $\ell_p$ ball $B_p^d$ is known in closed form, we "only" need to find the asymptotics of the $(d-1)$-dimensional surface area of this ball. It is easy to see that for $p\in(1,\infty)\setminus\{2\}$ this area is given by the formula 
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{vol}_{d-1}(\partial B_p^d)
 &=2^d\int_{S_p^{d-1}}\frac{\dd x_1\cdots\dd x_{d-1}}{\cos\theta} \\ 
  &=2^d\int_{S_p^{d-1}} \sqrt{1+\Big(1-\sum_1^{d-1}x_i^p\Big)^{2/p-2}\,\sum_1^{d-1}x_i^{2p-2}}\,
  \dd x_1\cdots\dd x_{d-1} \\ 
&=2^d\iint\limits_{a<1} \sqrt{1+(1-a)^{2/p-2}\,b}\,\,f_{d-1}(a,b)\dd a\dd b,  
\end{align*}
where $S_p^{d-1}:=\{(x_1,\dots,x_{d-1})\in(0,\infty)^{d-1}\colon\sum_1^{d-1}x_i^p<1\}$, $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors $(0,\dots,0,1)\in\R^d$ and 
$\vec\nabla G=\big(-\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1},\dots,-\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{d-1}},1\big)$, $G:=G(x_1,\dots,x_d):=x_d-F(x_1,\dots,x_{d-1})$, $F:=F(x_1,\dots,x_{d-1}):=\big(1-\sum_1^{d-1}x_i^p\big)^{1/p}$ 
(so that $(0,\infty)^d\cap\partial B_p^d=\{(x_1,\dots,x_d)\in(0,\infty)^d\colon G(x_1,\dots,x_d)=0\}$), $f_{d-1}$ is the joint probability density function (pdf) of the random variables (r.v.'s) $A:=\sum_1^{d-1}X_i^p$ and $B:=\sum_1^{d-1}X_i^{2p-2}$, and $X_1,\dots,X_{d-1}$ are independent r.v.'s uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,1)$.

Thus, it appears to mainly remain to find an appropriate asymptotics of $f_{d-1}(a,b)$ for $a<1$ and $d\to\infty$. This task may not seem exceedingly difficult, but it has eluded my efforts so far; perhaps someone else will be able to succeed here.